# NumberFormatException in converting string to byte

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get the MD5 format of string

**Code:**

```
fun getEncodedData(data: String): String? {

        val MD5 = "MD5"

        // Create MD5 Hash
        val digest = java.security.MessageDigest
            .getInstance(MD5)

        digest.update(data.toByte())
        val messageDigest = digest.digest()

        // Create Hex String
        val hexString = StringBuilder()
        for (aMessageDigest in messageDigest) {
            var h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF and aMessageDigest.toInt())
            while (h.length < 2)
                h = "0$h"
            hexString.append(h)
        }
        return hexString.toString()
    }
```

**There is a crash at:**  `digest.update(data.toByte())`. I get number format Exception

**Input I am passing for `data`**: `oEXm43`

There is no crash if I pass ex: `11` as a string for input `data`

Should the input always should be `integer` in the `string` or can it be a mixture of `number` and `characters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call the [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update(byte)) method that takes a single `byte` parameter, and using [`toByte`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-byte.html) which converts the entire string's numerical value to a single byte. This conversion method is what fails on non-numerical values inside a `String`.

Instead, you can use the variant of [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update(byte[])) with a `byte[]` parameter, and convert your `String` to an array of bytes (one per character) with [`toByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html):

```
digest.update(data.toByteArray())
```